# Blueprint, Sass and BrowserCMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, sass, blueprint-css, browsercms

I like quite much browserCMS. And I also favour sass and blueprint. I would like to make these things to play together. Although I read somewhere brosercms can sass and blueprint, it is not obvious for me how to really have it there. Can you recommend me steps how to reach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found out it is just straightforward. Behalf of browserCMS, I can simple add the compass gem to my rails app. Instead of the default styles given in the themes, stylesheets generated by compass will be used. So it just the same as with other rails applications. Nothing new under the sun.